# Android... How can I change my APK key?

Tags: android

I erased my original APK file that I uploaded to the market.  I created a new one, but the keys don't match.  Is there a way I change the current key of the file I just exported to the key that the android market requires or do I have to republish the whole app?

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to republish.

Comment: Just rebuild the original APK from source with the same key.  Deleting the APK means nothing, you just rebuild.  Or are you saying that you have lost the original keystore?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do:

1. Update with a new version an existing APK in the store
2. Re upload a same version of the existing APK in the store
3. Upload a new app to your store

In case its the option 1 or 2, you need to sign the APK with the EXACT SAME KEY you did before:

> http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

In case its the 3rd case, you can create a new key.

Always save the keys you use to sign yout APKs.